# MongoDb geoWithin in location array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor to query a mongodb collection. Right now this is my query where location is a 2dsphere index.

```
       messages.find({ 
         location: 
           { 
                $geoWithin :{$centerSphere : [ [ longitude, latitude ] , radius ] }
           }
       });
```

What would I need to change in this query if 'location' was an array of 2dsphere indexes and I wanted any entry who's array contained an element within `radius` of the `longitude, latitude` pair?

Answer (score 4):

With documents structured like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544e65dc0d86a53a8b32f7d0"),
    "locs" : [
        {
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                    -71.97,
                        43.77
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                    -63.97,
                    48.77
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

if you construct your 2dsphere index using

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "locs.loc" : "2dsphere })
```

then you can perform your desired query like

```
> db.test.find({ 
     "locs.loc" : { 
            "$geoWithin" : { "$centerSphere" : [ [ longitude, latitude ] , radius ] }
       }
   }
```

This work because indexes on arrays are multikey, and will create one index entry per array element for the document.